# Timeout on long ASP.Net Operation, for some Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have an application where it seems that for different users there is a different timeout and for some users the timeout is too soon.

It is a C#/.NET application that runs an ASPX based Website. Basically, you fill out a form and click on submit and then must wait a few minutes and you get the results. When I am connected to the system and perform this action it takes around nine minutes and I see the results.

But if another user performs this action after five minutes he gets displayed a “This page can’t be displayed” message in is browser (internet explorer –  the rest of the message is “*Make sure the web address http:// … is correct, Look for the page with bing, Refresh the page in a few minutes*”).

A little more background:

First the nine minutes seem long, but there is a huge amount of data (collection of datapoints over a span of a year) that is processed and displayed, and basically it works, so I don’t think it is necessary to discuss this point. For a lesser amount of data there are no problems.

The data from the database is obtained via C# and it performs the queries to a MS SQL database. 
First I thought it would help to set in the `web.config` in the `httpRuntime` tag the `executionTimeout` attribute. But the `compilation` tag has the `debug` flag set to true (and the application is deployed as release via visual studio on the server) – so the debug flag (as far I understand) overrides the executionTimeout anyways.

The Server on which the application is running is Windows Server 2012 R2 and for the site I also set under IIS in the advanced settings in the behavior / limits area the connection timeout on a higher value. But this hasn’t any effect.

I think I am missing some point, because as far I understand the deployed application doesn’t have any timeouts set (because of the debug flag) and this behavior seems user specific. 
Do you have any hints or ideas where I can look for?

**Edit**
In the comments was suggested to check the SQL Server logs for errors, the log was error free.

Comment: Internet explorer has a default keep-alive setting for requests - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/813827/how-to-change-the-default-keep-alive-time-out-value-in-internet-explor

Comment: I think it would be best to perform such a long-running operation asynchronously.

Comment: If you have a large database, it could be taking a long time to get results and different queries can take various amount of time.  So I would check the SQL Server logs to see if the errors are associated with the errors you are getting in your app.

Comment: @dunnel123 I didn't change the default keep-alive setting in the internet explorer. Besides this the default is 2 minutes, but the user times out at 5 minutes.

Comment: @jdweng I've checked the SQL Server logs and there were no errors.

Comment: The first thing we need to do is narrow down which component caused this issue. Did you see any exception in application event viewer? Secondly, have you checked something in httperr log?  If face this issue, I would probably capture hang or crash dump.

Comment: Check the Task Manager which application is running for the amount of memory.  The issue may be indirectly due to memory.  The data is transferred over TCP and issue may be related to the memory that TCP uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, it was a problem due to an older version of the browser that had some strict timeout settings. By switching to another version, this behavior doesn't show anymore.